# Adobe AIR SQLResult listener reached, but no data in SQLite

Tags: actionscript-3, sqlite, air

I'm currently working on a project using AIR and Flex that uses a remote data source to persist data locally in a SQLite database.  Currently, there's a lot of copy and paste code that I was trying to alleviate, so since we already use a DAO pattern with several common queries that get passed to it and a type that creates SQLStatement values, I figured I would simplify our codebase even more.

I applied the Adapter pattern to allow a wider range of possible database operations to be performed ([saveOrUpdate, find, findAll, remove] => [selectSingle, selectMultiple, insert, updateSingle, updateMultiple, deleteSingle, deleteMultiple]).  I also applied the Strategy pattern to two aspects of the statement runner: the first time for what sort of aggregated type to return (either an Array of records or an ArrayCollection of records) for the selectMultiple function; the second time for creating or not creating historical records (ChangeObjects).

After applying these patterns and testing some refactored code, it worked perfectly with an existing SQLite database.  I neglected to test its compatibility with the remote data source, since the saving mechanisms are used during that process as well.  After refactoring and simplifying our code and nearing the end of the development cycle, I tested the download.

It would read data from the SQLite database, despite the fact that there was actually no data in it according to sqlite3.

I will give the related piece of code for this.

```
public class BaseDaoAdaptee {
    private var returnStrategy: ReturnTypeStrategy;
    private var trackingStrategy: TrackingStrategy;
    private var creator: StatementCreator;

    public function insert(queryTitle: String, 
                           object: DaoAwareDTO,
                           parameters: Array, 
                           mutator: Function, 
                           handler: Function): void {
        var statement: SQLStatement;
        mutator = creator.validEmptyFunction(mutator);
        handler = creator.validFault(handler);
        statement = defaultStatement(queryTitle, parameters, handler);
        statement.addEventListener(SQLEvent.RESULT, 
            trackingStrategy.onInserted(object, mutator), false, 0, true);
        statement.execute();
    }
}
```

The code for the TrackingStrategy implemented:

```
public class TrackedStrategy 
    implements TrackingStrategy {
    public function onInserted(object: DaoAwareDTO, 
                               callback: Function): Function {
        return function (event: SQLEvent): void {
            var change: Change,
                id:Number = event.target.getResult().lastInsertRowID;
            creator.logger.debug((event.target as SQLStatement).itemClass + ' (id # ' + id + ') inserted');
            (object as Storeable).id = id;
            change = new Creation(object);
            change.register();
            callback();
        };
    }
}
```

The logger reads that various database records were inserted, and when stopped on a breakpoint in the above lambda, "object" has all proper values.  When running a Select statement in sqlite3, no records ever get returned.

Why would this happen?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out an open transaction on a SQLConnection value was the cause.  Got to love team projects.  Commit or rollback your SQLConnection transactions!